# Difference between the telegram (win1) desktop app and web interface when it is "managed by your organization"?

Tags: web-browser, corporate-policy, desktop, telegram

Sometime ago I was told by our cyber department that Telegram desktop app is not "safe" as it allows silent installation of programs (first I heard about it, and they could not back it by anything). Which makes me think they are more concerned about people's ability to share files within Telegram without "my organization" knowing about it.

So question is, what type of access does "my organization" has to my information when using Telegram web interface on Chrome or Firefox? Can they track what I type or the pictures I share? Or the files?

Comment: I think you have some faulty logic here. Did they say that the web interface was better? Or was their focus just the desktop app?

Comment: I think you misunderstood them. Possibly (no guarantees on these statements) just like with Microsoft Teams and similar apps, the native client does not have tracking, telemetry and other unwanted stuff blocked by an ad blocker, which is usually already available on a web browser. That's probably what they really meant by that.

Comment: @schroeder that they do not want to have the desktop app installed, but prefer to not use the web interface as well (but the web is not excluded)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you connect to the internet. If you have a proxy (transparent or not), the company have access to the traffic, and if the proxy does SSL Inspection (most of the enterprise proxies do it), they even have the traffic in clear.

In the latter case, they will have access to every single message, every picture, every file, everything. It does not mean they will store that and check later (that's unusual), but they have all traffic in clear and can feed that traffic to [Data Loss Prevention](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/data-loss-prevention-DLP) (DLP) tools.

I don't know if Telegram desktop application have any sort of encryption on top of TLS, but if it does, it would explain why company IT won't like it running, as any custom encryption could bypass the inspection tools.

Comment: So in the case of the web interface, they wont care as they can catch the traffic via http/s?

Comment: A web application have a more constrained environment to work with: it cannot run applications, cannot access arbitrary files, cannot receive external connections, cannot monitor anything outside its tab. A native application can do way more, so maybe that's why Telegram application is discouraged.